# Somehow AutoHotkey doesn't send Alt+keys to a program

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using the following AutoHotkey script:

```
Numpad4::Send !f
```

When pressing Numpad4 AutoHotkey is supposed to send "Alt+F" to the program currently opened.
Nothing happens however - I've also tried:

```
Numpad4::!f
```

and

```
Numpad4::Send {Alt}f
```

Any ideas how I can get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Numpad4::
KeyWait Alt
Send f
return
```

I know you technically want it to hit <kbd>alt</kbd> then <kbd>f</kbd>, but this has the same effect.

Comment: I'm also using

Numpad1::Send ^+g

and it works

Comment: @DDDD, I have edited my answer.

Comment: nope... it seems like he tries to enter the upper menu
like when you press Alt alone

Comment: @DDDD, are you sure there is something that the program does if you hit alt+f? Hitting it in most applications will just open the file menu, if it has one (because hitting alt "reveals" the menus and f is the shortcut key for the file menu, hitting as a key combo does the same thing as hitting alt alone then following up with f.)

Comment: It is sound editing software, it has lots of shortcuts. Alt+F is one of them, without using the menu.
So hitting alt and then F isn't the same as Alt+f

Comment: This is strange behavior of the Alt key with combinations...
It seems like Alt key pressed separately rather than other combinations like Ctrl...

Answer (score 1):

For Excel this AutoHotKey script sends <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> (paste special values)

```
alt & v::
Send, {LAlt Down}{e}{s}{v}{LAlt Up}{enter}
return
```

I think it's the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> that makes it work. (I probably should have asked and answered a more specific question and answered myself than replying here)